# keyframing Alpha in materials

Tags: materials, eevee-render-engine, transparency, keyframes

I am trying to make this plane transparent in the beginning and then slowly appear. With just the principle bsdf, i set the material blend mode to alpha clip and gave the color. So it's transparent in the first keyframe (600) and then opaque in the last (800). The problem here is right in between these keyframes, there is not smooth transition, just constant yet I can see in the properties window that the alpha is animating. I also tried to render this to test if it's just the viewport display, but there's no difference.
I'm wondering if this isn't the right method to animate the transparency of a mesh

Here's the scene
[image]

the plane has he alpha clip material

Here's he render viewport

[image]

This is he timeline showing he keyframes of he alpha

[image]

Here's part of the material settings

[image]

exactly on frame 701, it just immediately turns opaque

[image]

please help :'>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Alpha clip" clips considering the threshold as shown here. That's why the plane suddenly appears or disappears.

[image]

I think in your case you should prefer these settings:

[image]

Comment: The transition works fine now except wont fully cover the things behind it. just the meshes. The plane is meant to cover the whole scene as a transition. Is there another way?

Comment: What are these things other than meshes?

Comment: the other objects are grease pencil objects